# intellij: wizard to create facades for my entities

Tags: intellij-idea, session-bean

Right now I'm doing a tutorial in Java EE. Problem is:
The tutorial says that I have to create facades of my entities from my database. The tutorial is designed for the NetBeans IDE, but at work i must use IntelliJ. I'm not a big fan of IntelliJ at the moment but i have no choice. So like the title says: is there an easy way to create facades for my entities like there is in NetBeans?

[image]

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Uhm, no there is no such thing. IntelliJ actually requires you to be able to code yourself. Netbeans lacks that feature I think :).